# Can in do static site generation for an client side components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, static-site-generation

Im new to nextjs, I just trying to wrap my head around this new model. I think i now understand that were have rendering techniques like static site generation (SSR) and server side rendering(SSR). And were also have the concept of client and server components. The differents is server componets just return the html no javascript bundle. And cliend return html and javascript bundle that will help use to hydrate the page to make it interactive.

My question is can i have static site generation on an project that use client componets and still able deploy the project on a content delivery network (CDN). Like is the framework able to do that

I have read a number of blogs